# How to integrate a foreach with a complicated JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, arraylist

I want to connect my API to wordpress. My API returns this kind of results :

```
    <?php
$results = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xy67200/json/master/example2.json'));

$results= json_decode($results);
$articles[]=$results;


foreach ( $articles[0] as $article) {
    
    $fillable = [
        'field_5f48dca526171' => 'source->id',
        'field_5f48dcc226172' => 'source->name',
        'field_5f48dcd826173' => 'title',         
    ];

     foreach ($fillable as $key => $title){
        //update_field($key, $article -> $title, $inserted_article);
         print_r( $article -> $title);
        print_r("\n\n");
     }
}


?>
```

I want to have the 0 for id in the first row of $results. But with `'a' => 'source->id'`, it returns nothing but if I do this `'a' => 'source` I get an stdclass object.

Do you have a the solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a valid php code.

Comment: Hi, sorry. Now it's ok

Comment: Why do you need this `$fillable` array? Why not just use `$article['source']['id']`?

Comment: In Wordpress, I have a plugin "Advanced Custom Fields". This plugin generate a field which is linking with a variable. I'm following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWM41Rcao3s&t=1398s

Answer (score 1):

Change `$results= json_decode($results);` to `$results= json_decode($results, true);`. That will change it from an object to an array

From: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php "When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays."

Comment: Hi thank you, but when I do this, foreach ($fillable as $key => $value){

         print_r( $article[$value]);
        print_r("\n\n");
     }

of course with 'field_5f48dca526171' => '[source][Id]' .

I have the same issue the value isn't display, I think it's about of the $value

Comment: in fact print_r($article -> $title) doesn't work, but print_r($article -> source -> id) works. Even for an array, print_r( $article[$value]); doesn't work but separately print_r($article[source][id]